# Divide aggregate value using values from data frame in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`.

```
+---+-------------+----+
| id|       device| val|
+---+-------------+----+
|  3|      mac pro|   1|
|  1|       iphone|   2|
|  1|android phone|   2|
|  1|   windows pc|   2|
|  1|   spy camera|   2|
|  2|   spy camera|   3|
|  2|       iphone|   3|
|  3|   spy camera|   1|
|  3|         cctv|   1|
+---+-------------+----+
```

I want to populate some columns based on the below `lists`

```
phone_list = ['iphone', 'android phone', 'nokia']
pc_list = ['windows pc', 'mac pro']
security_list = ['spy camera', 'cctv']
```

I have done like below.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('cat', 
    F.when(df.device.isin(phone_list), 'phones').otherwise(
    F.when(df.device.isin(pc_list), 'pc').otherwise(
    F.when(df.device.isin(security_list), 'security')))
).groupBy('id').pivot('cat').agg(F.count('cat')).show()
```

I got the desired result.

Now I want to do some change to the code I want to populate the column value after I divide the `cat` column with the value in the `data frame` for that `id`.

I tried something like below but didn't get the correct result

```
df.withColumn('cat', 
    F.when(df.device.isin(phone_list), 'phones').otherwise(
    F.when(df.device.isin(pc_list), 'pc').otherwise(
    F.when(df.device.isin(security_list), 'security')))
).groupBy('id').pivot('cat').agg(F.count('cat')/ df.val).show()
```

How can I get what I want?

> edit

`Expected result`

```
+---+----+------+--------+
| id|  pc|phones|security|
+---+----+------+--------+
|  1| 0.5|     1|     0.5|
|  3|   1|  null|       2|
|  2|null|  0.33|    0.33|
+---+----+------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your desired output?

Comment: @pault I have updated the question with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aggregation would need an aggregation function, a simple column would not be identified**

Since `val` column contains same value for each group of `id` column, you can use `first` inbuilt function as

```
df.withColumn('cat',
              F.when(df.device.isin(phone_list), 'phones').otherwise(
                  F.when(df.device.isin(pc_list), 'pc').otherwise(
                      F.when(df.device.isin(security_list), 'security')))
              ).groupBy('id').pivot('cat').agg(F.count('cat')/ F.first(df.val)).show()
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+------------------+------------------+
| id|  pc|            phones|          security|
+---+----+------------------+------------------+
|  3| 1.0|              null|               2.0|
|  1| 0.5|               1.0|               0.5|
|  2|null|0.3333333333333333|0.3333333333333333|
+---+----+------------------+------------------+
```